# Filter with an exception for hidden input fields

Tags: jquery, filter

The following is obviously finding elements that start with the class "output_" and are visible. My question to you is how can I include hidden input fields?

```
$.each($(".output_"+value).filter(":visible"), function(index2, value2) {

    alert($(this).attr('id'))

});
```

Comment: You meant every hidden elements or hidden elements with specific classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can flatten the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) call right into the selector and then use a [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/):

```
$('.output_' + value + ':visible, input[type=hidden]').each(function(i, el) {
    alert(el.id);
});
```

There's no need to use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) here, you can just use [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) instead. Furthermore, there's no need for `$(x).attr('id')`, you can just grab the `id` property straight off the element with `x.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.add()` function like below

```
$.each($(".output_"+value).filter(":visible").add(":hidden"), function(index2, value2) {

    alert($(this).attr('id'))

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/add/